# When to close HTTP Client in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

My Flutter mobile app communicates with my back-end server. The docs say it's better to use `Client` class (`IOClient`) than plain `get`, `put`, etc. methods to maintain persistent connections across multiple requests to the same server.
[Docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Client/close.html) also say that:

> It's important to close each client when it's done being used; failing
> to do so can cause the Dart process to hang.

I don't understand when I need to close the client, because almost all app screens require HTTP connection to the same server. What's the best practice here?

**Update:**

Is it OK to close `Client` only before app is terminated, or should I close it every time app is hidden (goes to `paused` state)?

Comment: It seems that they removed your quoted line in the documentation. Which solution did you go with?

Comment: I've updated the link so it points to close method itself.
I only close the client before the app is terminated. It works for me, not sure if it causes any problems (which happen rarely).

Comment: I've been searching around and it seems that no dart code will be executed if the app is terminated (for example `dispose` of the first page). Where did you call the close method?

Comment: @HảiNguyễn I subscribed to app lifecycle changes and close the client inside `didChangeAppLifecycleState` method `if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached)`

Comment: Since app resources are disposed by default on app close, it's useless to handle that in such situation, And the Client dispose should not be handled since it's needed all the time. The documentation is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I personnaly think that closing client after each user action is the best practise.

What i call an "user action" can be constituted of multiple API request.

So i think the best is something like that:

```
var client = http.Client();
try {
  var response = await client.post(
      Uri.https('my-api-site.com', 'users/add'),
      body: {'firstname': 'Alain', 'Lastname': 'Deseine'});
  var Response = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)) as Map;
  ...
  // Add here every API request that you need to complete the users action
} finally {
  // Then finally destroy the client.
  client.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think this is the correct approach. When using a well designed API, a user action should only required a single API request. If you close the client after every user action it entirely eliminates the benefits of using a client.

Comment: Don't aggree with this. If a user in your app make an action then go to eat or go to bed or take an hour to do other things before using back your app, what is the benefit of maintaining the connection? 

And about well design API, if your UI need to dispaly (for example) different kind of datas is is really possible or sometime mandatory to make many API calls.

Comment: If a user doesn't use an app for over an hour then they're going to background it and there's a good chance the operating system will kill it off in that time, hence your app would exit and the connection would be closed anyway.

My use case is that I am designing an app and the web API at the same time so I can ensure each user action only needs one API call since I am designing the API as well.

Comment: Also I am using Flutter web, and on Chrome if a tab isn't used for over an hour it will kill the tab in the background, killing the flutter app.

Comment: @AdamGriffiths I think you misunderstood the the sentence "failing to do so can cause the Dart process to hang." 
This sentence says: if you don't close (in fact use the close() function) the **http** process will hang. 
You must understand that dart process refers to the http process, not the application.
To be shure, you can check the http source code of http client: https://github.com/dart-lang/http/blob/master/pkgs/http/lib/src/io_client.dart
Chek the comment of close method: `Terminates all active connections. If a client remains unclosed, the Dart process may not terminate.``

Comment: Also, don't forget that at low level, connections to server are made through a socket connection. 
So there is two endpoint for a connection: Your client and the server you are atempting to reach.
In most case the API serveur is apache or nginx (or node, iis, etc.) All of these server  implements sockets timeouts. because they can't maintained open cockets indefinitevely.
For apache the default is 300 seconds: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout

Comment: It is therefore illusory to want to keep a connection open on a server for an indefinite time, because after a certain timeout it is the server which will itself cut the connection. 
I think it's better to release the connection as soon as possible, because in case of many simultaneous connections, the API server will maintain opened sockets to the detriment of other users who would like to connect.

Comment: For example if you server accept 100 simultaneous connections and you keep open your connection until servers timed out, the 101+ user triying to connect can't connect and then you application really hang, but not for the same reasons.

Comment: You are correct that the dart process may not terminate. However do you think that when you open a Flutter app that two processes start? One dart process for the app and one process for http client? If not then the dart process is the same for the app and the http client.

I am not concerned about the server since as you said it will automatically close the connection after 300 seconds, so my server will not suffer from open connections, I am most concerned about the performance of my Flutter app.

Comment: That's not what i said. Dart don't spawn process when doing an http request. For having // process, you need to spawn an isolate. I don't thing you run your api call in a isolate (but this can be done).

Comment: About server i disagree, you are concerned once you have many end user using your  application. If you persist user connections during 5 minutes (300 seconds) and you server limit connections to 100 that mean that in 5 minutes you can have maximum 100 users. If you don't persist connections during 5 minutes, in the same 5 minutes, you can hava much more connections. So if you persist connections, you create a bottleneck at the server level.

Comment: Also, you says you are using Flutter to generate web applications, don't forget that Flutter will transpile your dart code (Dart is a language) to JavaScript (like Angular transpile TypeScript to Javascript for example). And with Javascript web applications, you are executing your app in the browser context.

Comment: We are arguing about points outside the scope of the question here. Ultimately the question is asking 'When to close the HTTP client?' However if we take your answer you are saying you should close it after every user request. If that's the case you do not get the benefits of the http client unless you make multiple requests per interaction which I do not. Therefore in my case your answer is the same as not using a HTTP client in the first place since I would get none of the benefits of it. I do not believe an answer which is the same as not using the client answers the original question.

Comment: My answer is clear and I maintain it. Besides, I encourage you to read carefully the documentation of the http package. It says: "If you're making multiple requests to the same server, you can keep open a persistent connection by using a Client rather than making one-off requests. If you do this, make sure to close the client when you 're done:"
under this, you can see an example that illustrate what this sentence mean.
This example is a `try ... finally`example where 2 requests are made (a post and a get).

Comment: This demonstrate exactly what i mean and this is the typical use as of package creator.

Example is: 
``var client = http.Client();
try {
  var response = await client.post(
      Uri.https('example.com', 'whatsit/create'),
      body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
  var decodedResponse = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)) as Map;
  var uri = Uri.parse(decodedResponse['uri'] as String);
  print(await client.get(uri));
} finally {
  client.close();
}``


Documentation page: https://pub.dev/packages/http

Comment: I can see that, however that is not my use case. In addition the person who originally asked the question and 24 other upvoters have a different use case as well. The use case is using the same HTTP client throughout the whole app and when to close it.

Comment: My last try. 
You have to understand that if you don't close the socket by calling the close method, internally dart:io which is the underlying paclage that is used by http package will recreate the connection each time the server close connection. So, wanting to maintain connection during the whole app has no sense because dart:io will silently close/create connections. So you can't use the same tcp socket connection during the whole app life.

Comment: I understand that, however the server only closes the connection after 5 minutes. In addition, each time the user makes a request that 5 minute timeout gets refreshed meaning connections that are in use every 1 or 2 minutes can stay alive for a long time. With your suggestion we would have to close the connection after each request and take the time to reopen it each time they perform a new action.

Comment: So you prefer having a thread on your API server that is idle for minutes, waiting a possible user request? Have you benchmark the lost time of close/open a socket versus redraw the user screen? Your approach will definitively not increase performance i think.
I wrote a node.js application that use sockets tcp connections to dozens of TCP servers (not HTTP) to poll status from them. Never close/open tcp connections to these servers was a performance concern. And polling time between 2 connections is every 2 seconds.

Comment: I do yes since this is an app for use by internal company employees only, and so the important thing is the absolute fastest app they can get to increase their productivity, regardless of how much server resource it uses

Answer (score 1):

## Don't close the HTTP Client

For some of you, it may sound odd, but the solution is as simple as **not to do that**.

### Why

In most cases, the HTTP Client should be available for the whole app run time. Also, app resources are **disposed automatically** when the app is closed by the user. For that reason, in most cases, we don't need to handle the disposal of the HTTP Client.

### When to dispose an HTTP Client?

Only if we want to run **a limited, one-time, predicted, season of HTTP requests**. In that case, you can dispose of the Client in many different ways (depending on your state management or the lifecycle that you want to trigger the disposal).

The `dispose()` function is common to all packages that handle cache and local resources. The documentation mentions that option, but it does not suggest you use it in every scenario. It should be handled in very specific scenarios only.

So for most of you, just don't dispose of the HTTP Client.

Comment: This is in direct contradiction to the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Client/close.html) which says `It's important to close each client when it's done being used; failing to do so can cause the Dart process to hang.` Unless you can prove this documentation is incorrect and the dart process will **never** hang as the result of an unclosed client, then this answer is potentially dangerous.

Comment: Since you always need the HTTP Client season and resources on the app run, you don't need to handle its disposal. When the user closes the app, all its resources are disposed of automatically. For that reason, not handling HTTP Client disposal is the correct answer in most cases. My answer explains that exactly, and your dislike just prevents other developers from reaching the right answer.

Comment: You have to understand that every package that uses resources has and suggests you use its disposal method. And it does important to dispose of resources when you stop using the service. In the case of an HTTP Client, you always need to communicate with your server, so you don't want to dispose of its resources the whole app run time.

Comment: The documentation says `It's important to close each client when it's done being used`. That is exactly why my answer is correct. Because in most cases, the HTTP Client is **always been used**.

Comment: You're correct that the HTTP client is always used. However if the app automatically disposed of the HTTP client automatically, why would the warning `failing to do so can cause the Dart process to hang.` need to be in the documentation in the first place? The creators of the package would simply say that you don't always need to close the http client since it will be done automatically.

Comment: You're directly contradicting the official documentation of the package without any evidence that the http client is properly closed. If other developers follow your advice they could potentially end up with Flutter apps hanging in production and have a really hard time debugging as to why.

Comment: The documentation mentions that because, in some specific scenarios, developers want to dispose of HTTP Client resources (basically when they know when they don't need to use it again, says as retrieving one-time data from a server on the app start).

Comment: You're completely ignoring the second part of the sentence in the documentation: `failing to do so can cause the Dart process to hang.`

Comment: **You have agreed** with me that we need to use the HTTP Client for the whole app season. And the documentation mentions that it's important to close the client **when it's done being used**. So I honestly don't understand why you disagree with this answer

Comment: I do agree that it is used for the whole app session. However there is nowhere in the documentation that says the HTTP client is 'disposed automatically when the app is closed by the user' as you say in your answer. In fact the documentation says `failing to do so can cause the Dart process to hang.` which specifically says you **must** manually close the client once it is done being used or the Dart process will hang. Your suggestion would leave the HTTP client unclosed (since it does not do it automatically) and lead to apps hanging.

Comment: If you have evidence that the HTTP client is automatically closed when the user exits the app **or** you can **guarantee** the app will not hang if you do not close the HTTP client yourself, I will accept your answer and award the bounty. As it stands however you have claimed the HTTP client is automatically closed when the user exits the app, which is in direct contradiction to the documentation, and you have provided no evidence to support your claim.

Answer (score 0):

##### Keep connections atomic per server interaction.

> almost all app screens require HTTP connection to the same server

One thing is that all screens make http calls, other thing is having constant high frequency interactions with the server.

Let's say we have a multiplayer app, that requires each second that passes to communicate with the server. If that was the case, leaving the client open would be critical. Even though you have the architectural consequence that the dart process would hang. This would mean that dart may not be the best solution for a high server traffic app.

To my understanding **your app is not the case**. You don't need to worry about leaving the connection open constantly, so you could only open and close it each time you need to use it without having to pay a high performance price.

It should be *seemless* to the user if you are opening a connection each time you try to consume your API.

Having said this, here are some other insights on this topic:

- A large amount of clients connected to the server, even when not active, may consume resources of memory or objects (for example, if there is one thread per connection). On the other hand, keeping the connection on, will allow the client to detect if there is a connection problem to the server much faster (if that even matters). [Extracted from this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110600/should-i-keep-a-socket-open-during-a-long-running-process)

Hopefully this will help you, given your use case, take a better decision.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of network traffic, it's better to use the same client throughout the app lifecycle. Establishing a new connection for each api is very expensive. However, as per the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Client/close.html),

**It's important to close each client when it's done being used; failing to do so can cause the Dart process to hang.**

Also, if client.close() isn't called, it doesn't mean that the server will keep the connection open forever. The server will close the connection if it is idle for a period more than the [HTTP Keep-Alive Timeout](https://blog.stackpath.com/glossary-keep-alive/). In this case, if the client sends a new request over the connection closed by server, he'll get a [408 Request Timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/408).

So, if you decide to use the same client throughout the app lifecycle, keep in your mind the two possible issues that you may run into.

Comment: You are right, but I have not managed to close the client when the app closes, please tell me how can I run code when the app is about to close to close the http client.

Comment: you can use AppLifecycleState.detached for that

Comment: That does not work on Flutter web

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68367780/flutter-web-how-to-detect-applifecyclestate-changes i think this may help

Answer (score 0):

Closing the HttpClient
HttpClient supports persistent connections and caches network connections to reuse them for multiple requests whenever possible. This means that network connections can be kept open for some time after a request has completed. Use HttpClient.close to force the HttpClient object to shut down and to close the idle network connections.

this way we must read the docs :

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html